# Как подвинуть UISearchController вниз?

Tags: swift, navigationbar, ios11

Когда UISearchController используется вместе с navigationItem.titleView:

navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logoMain"))

поле поиска "прилипает" к изображению в навбаре.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом можно его сдвинуть ниже на некоторое количество точек?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, что, на данный момент, никак. Если увеличить высоту навбара, будут визуальные косяки, когда поиск становится активным и уезжает в навбар. Единственный вариант - сделать саму картинку в навбаре чуть меньше по высоте, таким образом, паддинг между изображением и полем ввода станет чуть больше - так и сделал